# Querying MongoDB by a subclass field

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

SOLVED:

This works:

```
print("\nTrying to access by embedded_doc__embedded_int=1:")
for data in Doc.objects(embedded_doc__embedded_int=1):
    print(data)
```

You have to access subclass fields by using the main class variable name (not the class name), followed by __, followed by the subclass variable name, as above.

UPDATE:

My original question is below. I wrote an example to show in condensed and complete form what I'm trying to do.

In this example, I have a Doc class. Each Doc has an Embedded class called "embedded_doc". And within the Embedded class is an integer called "embedded_int".

My goal is to store Docs in MongoDB via MongoEngine, and query the database for Docs that have embedded_doc.embedded_int == 1. So far I haven't been able to figure out how.

```
class Embedded(EmbeddedDocument):
    embedded_int = IntField()
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other == self.embedded_int
    
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.embedded_int))
    
class Doc(Document):
    doc_str = StringField()
    embedded_doc = EmbeddedDocumentField(Embedded)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.doc_str} {str(self.embedded_doc)}"

data1 = Doc(doc_str = "first", embedded_doc = Embedded(embedded_int = 1))
data2 = Doc(doc_str = "second", embedded_doc = Embedded(embedded_int = 2))

#Gives correct output:
#Showing Doc objects in database:
#first 1
#second 2
print("Showing Doc objects in database:")
for data in Doc.objects():
    print(data)

#Gives correct output:
#Trying to access by doc_str='first':
#first 1
print("\nTrying to access by doc_str='first':")
for data in Doc.objects(doc_str='first'):
    print(data)

#ValueError: The source SON object needs to be of type 'dict' but a '<class 'int'>' was found
#During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
#mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Querying the embedded document 'Embedded' failed, due to an invalid query value
#print("\nTrying to access by embedded_doc=1:")
#for data in Doc.objects(embedded_doc=1): 
#    print(data)


#SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
#print("\nTrying to access by embedded_doc.embedded_int=1:")
#for data in Doc.objects(embedded_doc.embedded_int=1): 
#    print(data)


#NameError: name 'embedded_doc' is not defined
#print("\nTrying to access by embedded_doc.embedded_int==1:")
#for data in Doc.objects(embedded_doc.embedded_int==1): 
#    print(data)


#SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
#print("\nTrying to access by Embedded.embedded_int=1:")
#for data in Doc.objects(Embedded.embedded_int=1): 
#    print(data)


#Runs, but gives incorrect output:
#Trying to access by Embedded.embedded_int==1:
#first 1
#second 2
print("\nTrying to access by Embedded.embedded_int==1:")
for data in Doc.objects(Embedded.embedded_int==1): 
    print(data)
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm using Python + MongoDB + MongoEngine to get started with a NoSQL database.

I have a class, Article, which contains a field ArticleMetadata. In turn, ArticleMetadata contains a field called pub_year. I want to query my database for Articles that contain ArticleMetadata with pub_year == 2002. I'm trying this:

```
for article in Article.objects(ArticleMetadata.pub_year == 2002):
    print(article)
    input()
```

But it's printing every article in the database, not just the ones with pub_year == 2002. What do I need to change?

Comment: Ridiculously hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Try ArticleMetadata__pub_year = 2002 instead of ArticleMetadata.pub_year == 2002